# How to fetch JSON about a particular repository using github API

Tags: rest, github

I've read the official documentation ([GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview)) but it's not very clear about fetching information about a particular repo.

I want to fetch information (in JSON) about a particular repo of mine using browser only (and not Postman).

I tried this URL and it is fetching me all the repositories.

1. https://api.github.com/users/tmtanzeel/repos

But I need info about a particular repo only. I tried these:

1. https://api.github.com/users/tmtanzeel/repos/angular-project
2. https://api.github.com/users/tmtanzeel/repos?name=angular-project
3. https://api.github.com/users/tmtanzeel/repos?id=191101189

But none is working. Please pitch in.

Comment: Directly `https://api.github.com/tmtanzeel/get2moretravel` also it is not working. It just says `Not found`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. I figured it out.

**Solution:**

Instaed of `/<username>/repos` we should be doing `/repos/<username>`.

**Sample:**

```
https://api.github.com/repos/tmtanzeel/repo-name
```

A lot more information you'll find with the above URL:

[image]